# Enable Dialogbox only when data submited in a form through submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I am trying to save a data with next button.After entering the form when I click next button a popup dialogbox will open asking "Whether you wanna submit ur data?"

So for this What I did

In submit button I have this code :

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->submit('Next', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary','id'=>'movesubmitbtn'));?>
```

Its Cakephhp submit button

and here is my javascript code :

```
         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
         $(document).ready(function() {
         // Interrupt the submit function
    $('#movesubmitbtn').click(function(){
        if(confirm('This is your final submission of the data. Do you want to continue?')) { 
            return true;
        }
        else { 
            return false;
        }
    });
           movesubmitbtn
          });

        </script>
```

Please help me out,how to add disable property so that I will get the popuponly when data is present.

Comment: `confirm()` actually returns true or false all by itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <button id="submitBtn" type="submit" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
    <textarea id="textBox" rows="10" onblur="if(this.value == ''){document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = true;} else {document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = false;}"></textarea>
```

Or simpler:

```
<button id="submitBtn" type="submit" disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
    <textarea id="textBox" rows="10" onblur="document.getElementById('submitBtn').disabled = (this.value == '');"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery;

```
$('form').on('change', function(){
    // this will be triggered with every 'change' inside the form
    // e.g. Every time the user modifies a input
    // check if all (required) inputs contain a value
    if('' == $('#inputA').val() || '' == $('#inputB').val()){
        $('#movesubmitbtn').disabled = true;
    } else {
        $('#movesubmitbtn').disabled = false;
    }
});
```

Also consider putting the code you're using on the 'submit' event of the form instead of on the 'click' of the button. This will prevent the form being submitted if the users presses the 'enter' key inside a text field.